# React Child Component Api Calling Two Times (strict mode is off)

Tags: reactjs

Here, are three components User Details and its two Childs are UserSpecificData1 and UserSpecificData2.

In User Details component im getting User Details with userId by api calling.

Now i declared Two childs by passing that user id.

Problem is: Two child api is calling two times! Why? React strict mode is off.

Note: I noticed that child components are rendering two times by console.log

`

```
export const UserDetails = () => {
  const params = useParams(); // {userId: 223}
  useEffect(() => {
    if(params?.userId){
       getCustomerDetails(params.userId) // 223
}
  }, [params.userId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <UserSpecificData1 userId={params.userId}/>
      <UserSpecificData2 userId={params.userId}/>
    </div>
  );
};


// Component 1

const UserSpecificData1 = props => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [filteredBy, setFilteredBy] = useState({});
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('ASC');

  useEffect(() => {
    getSpecificDataOne({
      id: props.userId, //223
      filteredBy: filteredBy,
      page: currentPage,
      size: 10,
      sortBy: sortBy,
    })
  }, [sortBy, currentPage, filteredBy]);

  return <div>
  </div>

};


// Component 2

const UserSpecificData2 = props => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [filteredBy, setFilteredBy] = useState({});
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('ASC');

  useEffect(() => {
    getSpecificDataTwo({
      id: props.userId, //223
      filteredBy: filteredBy,
      page: currentPage,
      size: 10,
      sortBy: sortBy,
    })
  }, [sortBy, currentPage, filteredBy]);

  return <div>
  </div>

};
```

`

Comment: `props.userId` is missing in the `useEffect` deps array in both children, and additionally, both affects miss a guard inside at the top, `if (!props.userId) return`. The guard in the effect on the parent component implies that the param can sometimes not be defined. So you need to check that in the children as well, or it the effect will run again when it goes from undefined to defined.

Comment: not working actually.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i just reviewed your code and i came up with conclusion that you have to add a condition on both child useEffect where api is being called and check for prop.userId exist or not and don't forgot to passed it as dependency array.

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if(props?.userId){
    getSpecificDataTwo({
     id: props.userId, //223
     filteredBy: filteredBy,
     page: currentPage,
     size: 10,
     sortBy: sortBy,
    });
 }

},[sortBy, currentPage, filteredBy,props.userId]);
```

let me know if this works for you otherwise we will go for another way.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code isn't quite complete?

So I'm assuming you also have a `[content, setContent]` somewhere in the first component `UserDetails` - and if so, it'll first render the child components, and then, if `params.userId` exists, after the content has loaded it'll re-render.

A couple of ways to stop this, probably the best being surrounding your child components with `{ content && <Child 1 />...}`

So complete code would be:

```
export const UserDetails = () => {
  const params = useParams(); // {userId: 223}
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(params?.userId){
       getCustomerDetails(params.userId)
          .then(result => {
             setContent(result);
          }) // 223
    }
  }, [params.userId]);

  return (
    <div>
      { content &&
         <>
            <UserSpecificData1 userId={params.userId}/>
            <UserSpecificData2 userId={params.userId}/>
         </>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Personally I'd probably also put the userId into a hook and use that as the check, up to you which works better.